# Database.query is not returning data

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I have a problem with the **Database.query**. Its not returning the data to the Apex class, But when I am using the query editor, its showing the correct data.
My query is

```
List<CM_Group__c> e = Database.query('SELECT 
CM_Skill_Level__c,CM_Start_Date__c,Name FROM CM_Employee__c where 
CM_Start_Date__c != null');
System.debug(e);
```

When I am checking with the debug logs, it is showing empty.
But when I am using query editor, it is showing the below result:

[image]

Comment: What is the Org-Wide Default for `CM_Employee__c`? Who is the running user for `Database.query()`? Is the enclosing class declared `with sharing` or `without sharing`?

Comment: this is my class declaration . global class EMP_EmployeeAudit{ }

Comment: can you make it `global without sharing class EMP_EmployeeAudit`

Comment: @SalmaanC, I understand, but that does not answer all of the questions I asked. Salesforce record-level visibility is a big and complex topic, and we need a lot of details from you to give you a specific answer, even if the problem seems simple. Would you please expand the code included in your question to show the class where you are invoking this query, tell us who is running the code, and clarify the sharing regime on this object?

Comment: If you have not already, I would encourage you to complete security-focused modules on Trailhead, such as [this one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_security) and [this one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_basics_dotnet/execution_context), along with the [sharing Apex documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm).

Comment: @DavidReed , this is my class
global class EMP_EmployeeAudit {
global void execute(){
     List<CM_Employee__c> e = Database.query('SELECT CM_Skill_Level__c,CM_Start_Date__c,Name FROM CM_Employee__c where CM_Start_Date__c != null');
System.debug(e);
for(CM_Employee__c emp : scope){
if(emp.CM_Start_Date__c != null){
integer diff = emp.CM_Start_Date__c.daysBetween(Date.today());
integer totalYear = diff/365;
if(totalYear < 1){
emp.CM_Skill_Level__c = 'Junior';
 e.add(emp);
 }
}
update e;
    }  
}

Comment: @DavidReed ,I am running the code with sysAdmin privilege and i create,edit,delete,update and view of employee object

Comment: just to be sure - you see this behavior in anonymous apex? or in a testmethod. If a testmethod, unless you mock the data, it will return nothing